# Update all values in a DynamoDB attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there an approach for updating all items in an attribute(column) ?. 
I'm updating the values one by one using a for loop, but it takes a while. I can easily update a whole row in my table by benefiting from DynamoDB mapper, but cannot find a similar functionality for an attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the only way is to do a scan over the hash space and update each item.